# Referance multiple documents Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference

I'm trying to connect 3 different documents using mongoose (mainly to learn how to use it), I've set up 3 different schemas as follows:

(all of them are in there own files)

```
const Books = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  description: String,
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Authors' },
  stores: [{
    available: Number,
    store: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Stores' }
  }]
});

exports.Books = mongoose.model('Books', Books);

const Authors = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: String,
  born: Date,
  died: { type: Date, default: null }
});

exports.Authors = mongoose.model('Authors', Authors);

const Stores = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  description: String,
  address: String
});

exports.Stores = mongoose.model('Stores', Stores);
```

and then I add the following data:

```
author.name = 'Jonathan Swift';
author.description = 'old satiric bloke';
author.born = new Date(1667, 10, 30);
author.died = new Date(1745, 9, 19);
author.save()
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .then(() => console.log('author saved'));

store.name = 'Book shop 1';
store.description = 'This is where the cool kids buy all there books!';
store.address = 'La La Land, 123 Combaja street';
store.save()
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .then(() => console.log('store saved'));

book.title = 'gullivers travels';
book.author = '58a79345711f2350999e0911'; // _id from the author save
book.description = 'A book about a big guy in a small world';
book.stores = [{
  available: 8,
  store: '58a79345711f2350999e0912' // _id from the store save
}];
book.save()
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .then(() => console.log('store saved'));
```

The problem I find is that when I run `book.find()` it returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58a795b8298b50527412815c",
    "description": "A book about a big guy in a small world",
    "author": {
      "_id" : "58a79345711f2350999e0911",
      "born" : -9532947600000,
      "died" : -7075130400000,
      "description" : "old satiric bloke",
      "name" : "Jonathan Swift",
      "__v" : 0
    },
    "title": "gullivers travels",
    "__v": 0,
    "stores": [
      {
        "available": 8,
        "store": "58a79345711f2350999e0912",
        "_id": "58a795b8298b50527412815d"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what I was expecting/hoping for was to get the entire store as well the same way as with the author, have I missed something or how should I go about this to achieve the expected result?
I've tried `populate` but without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Books` model `author` & `stores.store` are reference, you shouldn't have `author` field populated if you don't use `populate()`.

If you specify directly the `_id` of your store & author you have just created :

```
var author = new Authors({
    name: 'Jonathan Swift',
    description: 'old satiric bloke',
    born: new Date(1667, 10, 30),
    died: new Date(1745, 9, 19)
});

author.save();

var store = new Stores({
    name: 'Book shop 1',
    description: 'This is where the cool kids buy all there books!',
    address: 'La La Land, 123 Combaja street'
});

store.save();

var book = new Books({
    title: 'gullivers travels',
    author: author._id, // _id from the author save
    description: 'A book about a big guy in a small world',
    stores: [{
        available: 8,
        store: store._id // _id from the store save
    }]
})

book.save();
```

`Books.find()` gives the expected result :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42e00",
    "title": "gullivers travels",
    "author": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42dfe",
    "description": "A book about a big guy in a small world",
    "__v": 0,
    "stores": [
      {
        "available": 8,
        "store": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42dff",
        "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42e01"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you want `stores.store` & `author` populated, use :

```
Books.find().populate([{path:'author'},{path:'stores.store'}]).exec(function(err, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
});
```

It gives as expected `author` & `stores.store` both populated :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42e00",
    "title": "gullivers travels",
    "author": {
      "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42dfe",
      "name": "Jonathan Swift",
      "description": "old satiric bloke",
      "born": "1667-11-29T23:00:00.000Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "died": "1745-10-18T22:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "description": "A book about a big guy in a small world",
    "__v": 0,
    "stores": [
      {
        "available": 8,
        "store": {
          "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42dff",
          "name": "Book shop 1",
          "description": "This is where the cool kids buy all there books!",
          "address": "La La Land, 123 Combaja street",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "_id": "58a7a2529a8b894656a42e01"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: wow ok so that's where I made my mistake, thanks a lot mate! do you have any idea who the author is populated for me btw? (using postman if that helps to narrow it down)